# Making unordered initialization statc ordered

Tags: c++, c++11

The following class uses the CRTP to attempt to add types to a std::vector that has a Schwarz counter ensuring initialization order.  According to 3.6.2/2 the member h_ has unordered initialization.  How would I change this to ensure that it has ordered initialization?  I would like for the deriving class to have to do nothing more than correctly inherit from the class.

```
#ifndef P_H_
#define P_H_

#include "PR.h"

template <typename T>
class P
{
   class helper
   {
   public:
      helper()
      {
         PR.push_back(typeid(T));
      }
   };
   static helper h_;
};

template <typename T>
typename P<T>::helper P<T>::h_;

#endif
```

Comment: You can choose when to initialize h_ using construct on first use : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Construct_On_First_Use

Comment: @ruslo It's a template, therefore ok (it's an exception to the ODR). In fact, [temp]/6 "A [...] static data member of a class template shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is implicitly instantiated"

Comment: @Graznarak So you need to access `h_` at load-time? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @DyP I am trying to use h_ to force code (the constructor) to be run before main() is called.  I actually do not want the inheriting class to even know about it.

Comment: @Graznarak Then what's the problem with *unordered initialization*? There's only a general requirement for any dynamic initialization: [basic.start.init]/4 "It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
duration is done before the first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized."

Comment: @DyP PR is defined in a different translation unit than h_.  h_ populates PR.  It is highly likely that main will use PR long before it uses anything in the translation units that subclass P.

Comment: Then even ordered initialization won't save you. The order of dynamic initialization of global variables in different TUs is either unsequenced or indeterminately sequenced if they're initialized before `main` (and it is implementation-defined whether they are initialized before the first statement of `main` or not). Read the example in [basic.start.init]/4, it covers your case. [a.lasram](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1003615/a-lasram) offered a solution: use a function instead of `PR` and do the `init` within that function.

Comment: Ordered initialization does help, when using a Schwarz counter.  The counter can be used to make sure that PR is initialized before anything else in the translation unit, assuming that the header is included before the use of PR.

Comment: So, actually, your helper ctor uses a Schwarz counter? Could you please include that in your code example?

Comment: No, PR uses a Schwarz counter.  That way I can guarantee that PR is valid before h_ is constructed.

Comment: I see. The only way to make it initialization *ordered* and keep it a template is to explicitly specialize it, and that would probably break the purpose of the template. I'd therefore recommend using the [construct-on-first-use](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Construct_On_First_Use) idiom as suggested by [a.lasram](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1003615/a-lasram) *instead* of the Schwarz counter. Or you invoke the Schwarz counter inside the `helper` ctor (static init is before *any* dynamic init).

Answer (score 0):

The standard pattern for this type of problem is to use a generator instead of exposing the global static variable.  (This is an old problem in C++)

So change:

```
static helper h_ ;
```

to:

```
static helper & h_() ;
```

and define it like this:

```
template <typename T>
typename P<T>::helper & P<T>::h_()
{
  static P<T>::helper value_ ;
  return value_ ;
}
```

Thus it will be guaranteed to be initialized before used.